# Can I set recursion depth more than 10^12 in python3?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to use a recursive function with almost 10^12 of recursion depth. I used `setrecursionlimit(10 ** 12)` , but error occurred with error message;
`OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int`

Should I change the solution that can solved in lower recursion depth? Or, is there any way that can set the recursion depth as 10^12 in python3?

Comment: Best of all is to avoid recursion in the first place. Second, when you have to use recursion, is to only use it where the structure has naturally low depth. Third, try to convert what you have into the second case.

Comment: "I'm trying to use a recursive function with almost 10^12 of recursion depth" **Why**? Please keep in mind that the reference Python implementation *does not eliminate tail calls*. Every recursive call must allocate memory, so you would need many terabytes of RAM (or much slower SSD/HDD swap space) to do this, even without considering the actual calculation.

Comment: This smells a lot like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Also, even calling a function that does nothing (and isn't recursive) takes some time. There is quite a bit of overhead for Python function calls. 10^12 calls, on my machine, would take about 18 hours.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show us the code and what you expect it to do.

Comment: What could you possibly be doing that actually needs to repeat 10^12 times? Whether you do it using recursion or iteration, it will take forever. If each iteration takes a microsecond, that's 10^6 seconds, which is over 11 days.

Comment: @Barmar ITYM "microsecond".

Comment: If you truly do need that much recursion, and there's no iterative solution, then you should be using a language like LISP which is designed for recursion. Python is not. But as was already stated, this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks for all response, I find my question was quite dumpt... I'll try another solving way.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No.  The value is too large the parameter type of the function that sets the depth limit.

The long answer is "You shouldn't have to" because that depth level is a clear indicator that recursion isn't the best approach.  Any recursive function can be converted to an equivalent (and usually faster / more efficient) iterative alternative.  You may want to look into the deque module to help with the conversions of the stack management.

Answer (score 0):

The max recursion limit is [platform dependent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit). You're limited in range to a signed C integer.

On my system that's a 4 byte (32-bit) signed int.

```py
>>> import ctypes
>>> print(ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int))
4
```

```py
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(2**31)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int

>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(2**31-1)  # no exception
```

As explained in other answers/comments, I would never attempt to approach that limit in practice. Every recursive solution can be converted to iteration.